# not able to add data from web page to database

Tags: php, html, sql

this is my form .html file getting connected to adddatabase.php page .having firstname and secondname

```
       <form action="addtodatabase.php" method="post">
       <div class="container">
       <form class="form-inline">
       <fieldset>
       <legend>Security Department User Registration</legend>
       <div class="form-group">
       <label for="Firstname">First Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Text input"><br/>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
       <label for="Secondname">Second Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Secondname" name="secondname" placeholder="Text input"><br/>
        </div>
       </form>

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
       </form>
```

addtodatabase.php page as follows .

```
     if (isset($_POST)) { 
     $firstname  = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '';
     $secondname = isset($_POST['secondname']) ? $_POST['secondname'] : '';
     echo 'Your first name is ' .$firstname. '<br>'; 
     echo 'Your second name is ' .$secondname. '<br>'; 
     }
     mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO form_details(firstname,secondname)
            VALUES('$firstname','$secondname')");
```

Comment: your submit button must be inside the form , as long as you are not handling the submission using javascript

Comment: 1. submit button must be inside form (if page refresh is used to submit the form).2. `$connect` code is missing

Answer (score 0):

You have form inside a form which is wrong. Do it like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="addtodatabase.php" >
      <!-- Your inputs -->
</form>
```

Also, put your submit button inside the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="addtodatabase.php" >
      <!-- Your inputs -->
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Or if the submit button is outside, set the `form` attribute of the button to the `id` of the `form`:

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="addtodatabase.php" >
      <!-- Your inputs -->
</form>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" form="myForm" />
```